# MSYS2: Wrong pkg-config.exe path on Meson

Tags: makefile, qemu, msys2, pkg-config, meson-build

I want to cross-compile a program (QEMU) in MSYS2 using Meson.
During the configuration phase Meson throw an error for a missing dependency

```
../meson.build:553:2: ERROR: Dependency "pixman-1" not found, tried pkgconfig
```

I checked the log and I got

```
...
Determining dependency 'pixman-1' with pkg-config executable 'C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin/pkg-config.EXE'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\pkgconfig;C:\msys64\mingw64\share\pkgconfig
env[PKG_CONFIG_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH]: C:/msys64/mingw64/include
env[PKG_CONFIG_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH]: C:/msys64/mingw64/lib
Called `C:\msys64\usr\bin/pkg-config.EXE --modversion pixman-1` -> 1

Run-time dependency pixman-1 found: NO (tried pkgconfig)

../meson.build:553:2: ERROR: Dependency "pixman-1" not found, tried pkgconfig
...
```

The path to the pkg-config executable uses the Windows format and this is not valid in UNIX.

How can I update the path using the correct UNIX format? Is it a Meson or MSYS2 error?

Thanks!

Comment: What terminal do you run this from (and which MSYS2 environment)? What's in the PATH? How did you install pkgconfig and meson?

Comment: It should be the default terminal (Mintty) and MINGW64 env. The PATH is "/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
". I installed meson and pkgconfig using pacman (I don't remember the package name).

Comment: Make sure the pkg-config and meson package names started with `mingw-w64-x86_64-...`. The unprefix packages are for the MSYS env.

Comment: I reinstalled all the packages with the "mingw-w64-x86_64-" prefix and now it is working! Why did I get this weird path issue? pkgconfig was already running also before the reinstallation.

Comment: MSYS2 has some magic to convert between linux and windows paths (msys apps do that when they launch windows apps), maybe in your case this conversion was good enough.